# How to pass url through two functions - Callback

Tags: python, callback, scrapy, yield

**Set-up**

I'm scraping housing ads with scrapy: per housing ad I scrape several housing characteristics.

Scraping the housing characteristics works fine.

---

**Problem**

Besides the housing characteristics, I want to scrape one image per ad.

I have the following code:

```
class ApartmentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = 'apartments'
start_urls = [
    'http://www.jaap.nl/huurhuizen/noord+holland/groot-amsterdam/amsterdam'
    ]

def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.xpath(
                '//*[@id]/a',
                ).css("a.property-inner::attr(href)").extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                    callback=self.parse_ad) # parse_ad() scrapes housing characteristics
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href),
                    callback=self.parse_AdImage) # parse_AdImage() obtains one image per ad
```

So, I've got two `yield` commands, which does not work. That is, I get the characteristics, but not the images.

I can comment the first one, such that I get the images.

How do I fix this such that I get both? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the intent behind yielding twice? It seems like the most obvious solution here would be to just send both at the same time.

Comment: I want both the characteristics and the image. So two yields, since I do not know how to command it such that one yield gives me the desired result. Clearly, this 'intuitive' solution failed.

Comment: Why not just yield a tuple of both results?

Comment: Could you show me what to tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Just yield them both together.

```
yield (scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_ad), scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(href), callback=self.parse_AdImage))
```

On the receiving end, grab both as separate values

```
characteristics, image = ApartmentSpider.parse(response)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm not sure however what you mean with 'on the receiving end'?

Comment: Wherever you're capturing the value returned from the yield. You're changing your return type to a tuple. To preserve the same behavior you currently have now, put the two variables you're using today to capture this information on the same line, left of the equals sign, separated by a comma.

Answer (score 0):

I have two major suggestions:

**Number 1**

I would strongly suggest re-working your code to actually farm out all the info at the same time.  Instead of having two separate parse_X functions...just have one that gets the info and returns a single item.

**Number 2**

Implement a Spider Middleware that does merging/splitting similar to what I have below for pipelines.  A simple example middleware is https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/ebef6d7c6dd8922210db8a4a44f48fe27ee0cd16/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py.  You would simply merge items and track them here before they enter the itempipelines.

WARNING DO NOT DO WHAT's BELOW.  I WAS GOING TO SUGGEST THIS, AND THE CODE MIGHT WORK...BUT WITH SOME POTENTIALLY HIDDEN ISSUES.

IT IS HERE FOR COMPLETENESS OF WHAT I WAS RESEARCHING -- IT IS RECOMMENDED AGAINST HERE:https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/1915

Use the item processing pipelines in scrapy.  They are incredibly useful for accumulating data.  Have a item joiner pipeline who's purpose is to wait for the two separate partial data items and concatenate them into one item and key them on the ad id (or some other unique piece of data).

In rough not-runnable psuedocode:

```
class HousingItemPipeline(object):
    def __init__():
        self.assembledItems = dict()
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        if type(item, PartialAdHousingItem):
            self.assembledItems[unique_id] = AssembledHousingItem()
            self.assembledItems[unique_id]['field_of_interst'] = ...
            ...assemble more data
            raise DropItem("Assembled it's data")
        if type(item, PartialAdImageHousingItem):
            self.assembledItems[unique_id]['field_of_interst'] = ...
            ...assemble more data
            raise DropItem("Assembled it's data")
        if Fully Assembled:
            return self.assembledItems.pop(unique_id)
```